# How can I save a file as a string array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to save a file line by line as a string array, but I am a beginner and confused.

```
package com.java24hours;

import java.io.*;

public class ShorteningVelocity {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException {

        FileReader SVfile = new FileReader(new File("C:\\Documents\\10-27-15110mMKPSS3.dat"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(SVfile);
        String temp = br.readLine();
        while (temp != null) {
            temp = br.readLine(); //reads file line by line 
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a beginner with your questions I'm also confused ... what is your question? Where do you have a problem?

Comment: Use [`Files.readAllLines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-).

Answer (score 2):

Java Arrays can't grow in size, so you use a list (from java.util). The lists grow dynamically, so you can use `add()` as often as you want. As a list can potentially hold everything, you specify what you want it to contain by using `List<TypeOfWhatYouWantToStore>`. The List class is called a generic class because of that.

Converting it to an array (because that is what you wanted) is a bit strange. You allocate the array with the size of the list and then you use `toArray` on the list. This returns the list, converted as an array. It must take the array as a parameter, because the compiler needs that when compiling with generics.

```
package com.java24hours;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ShorteningVelocity {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException {

        FileReader SVfile = new FileReader(new File("C:\\Documents\\10-27-15110mMKPSS3.dat"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(SVfile);
        String temp = br.readLine();
        List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (temp != null) {
            tmpList.add(temp);
            temp = br.readLine(); //reads file line by line 
        }
        String[] myArray = new String[tmpList.size()];
        myArray = tmpList.toArray(myArray);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Using `Files.readAllLines()` (see comments on your question) is easier and potentially faster, but using this loop, you can see more of what's going on.

**EDIT 2:** It is more common use this loop:

```
        String temp;
        List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) { 
            tmpList.add(temp);
        }
```

The loop is now doing the following:

- Read `br.readLine()` into `temp`
- If `temp` is null, leave the loop
- If `temp` is not null, add it to the list

You can also print the array by doing:

```
for (String str : myArray) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: *"It is more common to swap the lines inside the loop"* It is "more common" to add `null` as the last element to the list? You should use a proper `while` loop instead.

Comment: Oh right.... fixing it

Comment: @Tom should be okay now

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Documents\\10-27-15110mMKPSS3-out.dat");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(bw);

            FileReader SVfile = new FileReader(new File("C:\\Documents\\10-27-15110mMKPSS3.dat"));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(SVfile);
            String temp;
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //reads file line by line 
                System.out.println();
                outFile.println(temp);
            }
            outFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is great thank you!!

Comment: ChibiChibi, if my answer is the best, can you check my answer please?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File("D:\\input.txt"));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String temp;

        while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            tmpList.add(temp);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] myArray = new String[tmpList.size()];
    myArray = tmpList.toArray(myArray);
    for(int i = 0; i< myArray.length ; i ++){
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }
```